# Java Discord API - get Member from @mention

Tags: java, discord

The command is !info @user. I want to get a member from the @mention.

I couldn't find any method doing this. I just found a method that gets a User by a Tag but i need a member.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [getMentionedMembers()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getMentionedMembers()) method.

```java
if(message.getMentionedMembers().size() == 0) return;
Member member = message.etMentionedMembers().get(0);
```